# Online work activity log

Tags: web-apps, project-management

I'm looking for a service that allows me to log my work activity in real time and has a presentable/professional UI.

I would like to send a link to someone and have them see the project progress and what I'm currently working on.

So far I've only heard about services like Upwork/Freelancer that have similar activity trackers, but I would like it to be independent of a specific platform.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "independent of a specific platform," so I'm not posing this as an answer, but I've been very happy with Freshbooks.  It used to be free for a small number of clients, but I think they now charge.  But it's very presentable.  You can use it for invoicing, too.